# "Distance" between 2 sets.

Tags: calculus, metric-spaces

Let $(\mathbb{R^d},d)$ be a metric space.

Given 2 non empty sets $C,K$ we will define $d(C,K) =  \inf\{d(a,b):a\in C,b\in K\}$

I need to prove, that if $ \emptyset\neq K\subseteq\mathbb{R}^{d}$  is compact, and $ \emptyset\neq C\subseteq\mathbb{R}^{d}$ is closed, then there are $ c\in C \;, k\in K$ such that $$d(c,k)=d(C,K) =  \inf\{d(a,b):a\in C,b\in K\}$$

Also, I need to show why it fails when we are not over $\mathbb{R^d}$.

Answer (score 1):

Let $f : K \longmapsto \mathbb{R}$ such that $f(k) = \inf\limits_{c \in C}d(k,c)$, $f$ is continuous

(Intuitively seems reasonable that if we are arbitrarily close to $k$, $\inf\limits_{c \in C}d(k,c)$ won't change much)

Since $f$ takes real values and $f$ is a compact, $f$ admits a minimum $\bar{k} \in K$.

First we notice that $$d(K,C) = \inf\limits_{c \in C}d(\bar{k},c)$$

Since RHS is an infimum on the elements of $C$, it exists $(c_{n})_{n \in \mathbb{N}} \in C$ such that $d(\bar{k},c_{n}) \to \inf\limits_{c \in C}d(\bar{k},c)$ as $n \to \infty$

But since $C$ is closed, we have that $\inf\limits_{c \in C}d(\bar{k},c)
\in C$, which proves the assert.

> Edit : For the counterexample I suggest you to try $X = \mathbb{R}-\left\lbrace 2 \right\rbrace$, $K = [0,1] \subset X, C = [2,3] \cap (\mathbb{R}- \left\lbrace 2 \right\rbrace) \subset X$ with the induced topology.

Answer (score 1):

Basically you need to show that the infimum is actually a minimum (meaning that there exist two points that realize the inf), and you can do that easily when you have compactness and closeness in $\mathbb{R}^d$. You want to use compactness for the existence of minimum for continuous functions from compact sets to $\mathbb{R}$ and closeness to say that the limit point of some convergent sequence in $C$ is actually an element of $C$.
The strategy is to first find a point in $K$ that minimizes the distance from $C$. You can show that the function $d(k,C): K\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ is continuous and use compactness or you can do like this:
Define $K_n=\{k\in K \ s.t.\ d(k,C)\leq D+1/n\}$ where $D$ is distance between the two sets (which is an infimum). Now since $K$ is compact and $K_n\supset K_{n+1}$ are closed sets in a compact set, therefore compact, you should know that their intersection must be not empty. Call $p$ a point in this intersection, it is easy to see that it minimizes the distance $d(k,C)$ among all $k\in K$. Now do the same thing for C: define $C_n=\{c\in C s.t. d(k,c)\leq D+1/n\}$: if you take any sequence $(c_n)\subset C \ s.t. \ c_n\in C_n$ for all $n\in \mathbb{N}$ by triangular inequality you have that this is a Cauchy sequence and since it is in a closed subset of $\mathbb{R^d}$, it must converge to some point in the set C, call it $c^*$. Finally $(k, c^*)$ are the points you were looking for. I'm not sure how to find a counterexample when you're not on $\mathbb{R}^d$ but I think the thing that goes wrong is that you might not have the limit point of the last sequence if you don't have a complete metric space.

EDIT: I realized that in order to say that the sets $K_n$ are closed you might need continuity of the distance $d(k,C)$, so it doesn't really save you any time, but it's anyway a very common argument to make when you have compactness so maybe it's nice to see it anyway